# HTTP Request on a domain with a custom IP

Tags: ruby, http, dns, request

I'm trying to make an HTTP request to a domain www.example.com which contains at least 10 known IP addresses.

If I do the request on www.example.com, the domain resolves to one random IP Address and usually the same for a given client. I can't use the IP itself instead of the domain.

How could I use these 10 IP addresses dynamically to make 10 different requests with this single domain www.example.com ?

I know I can change the associated IP to a domain with the hosts file but is it possible to do it programmatically ? What should I look for ? If you have any ideas in PHP or Ruby I would be glad to here them.

Comment: It looks like it would be possible to programmatically change the host in ruby : https://github.com/bjeanes/ghost
Not very clean, but it may do the trick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use somethink like that in php : https://gist.github.com/AurelienLavorel/5609769abe835de918ec

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly curl I was using, you made my day with the "CURLOPT_HEADER, Host:" parameter. I think in ruby we have to simple set the host header too then.

Answer (score 0):

Perharps you could do it with a dns resolver between your client and the target ips, that would be configured to reply each of the ips in sequence for that domain ?

Alternately, you change the host file on your client machine before each request on the target domain. Simpler, but not very clean.